# Italics on Closing > Off-Topic dialog oddly suspended

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, design

If you go to a question that has a pending close vote for a custom off-topic reason whose text includes italics on a line that coincides with the pending close vote count for that reason, the italics get dragged down to the margin-bottom of the count.

This sounds pretty obscure, except that it happens on what will probably end up being a pretty popular custom closure reason, the "must demonstrate a minimal understanding" reason.

Here is what mine looks like:

[image]

Here is [one such example you can see for yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425344/importing-database-from-an-sftp-server-in-windows-azure), at least for now.

This is being observed by @Lamak in Windows 7 + Chrome 27, and by me in Mac OS 10.9 and Chrome 27.

(As an aside, should the word *must* in those reasons be bolded as well?)

Comment: I can see it with Chrome 27 in Windows 2003.